# Azure Application Insights Custom User Flows

Tags: pandas, azure, session, dataframe, azure-application-insights

I am using Azure Application Insights to track user flows (logged in, clicked button X, directed to page Y, clicked button Z, etc) on my web app, but AII only saves data from the past 90 days. I want to create graphs of user flows as [Sankey Plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram). I've had a continuous export set up for a while, so I have many CSVs for each day it has been exported with columns like event name, session Id, user Id, timestamp, etc.

I've joined all these CSVs together in an Azure Databrick in one large dataframe with all recorded events. I believe the best approach is to group by session Id, add indexes for the order of events, and then group by that index so that the group for index 1 has all the logins, and the group for index 2 has whatever users do after logins. From there I'm not entirely sure what I'd do, but for now I am stuck on creating these dataframes / grouped dataframes.

Any advice about taking a different approach or creating these grouped data frames would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!